# Polymorphism: calling subclass' method from superclass' variable

Tags: java, polymorphism

In Java, when a method is going to be executed, it's declaration is first searched for at the object's real class (that defines the real type of the object). If it's not found, then the superclass is checked. If isn't found there either, the next parent class is checked, and so on. However, look at the example below:

```
   SuperClass s = new SubClass(list of parameter);
   s.someMethodExistOnlyInSubClass();
```

This will give me a compile time error. I thought that, as mentioned above, it would first look for `someMethodExistOnlyInSubClass()` at `SubClass`, verify that it exists there and then execute it right away. If I use a variable of the type `SuperClass` to reference an instance of `SubClass` some parameters will go to `SuperClass`'s constructor through a call to `super()` and the object will be instantiated there. In this context, to where have the remaining parameters gone?

Comment: You declared it as type SuperClass, not as type SubClass, meaning it is limited to the members of SuperClass

Comment: "this will gives me a runtime error" this will give a compile time error.

Comment: When you have a fruit object, you can't just treat it as apple. Also, Andy is as always fully correct: the above would not even compile (in Java).

Comment: @Stultuske i understand that but i still don't know why polymorphism can call for example: SubClass toString method when it is invoked from a SuperClass variable

Answer (score 5):

By assigning a reference to an instance of `SubClass` to a variable of the type `SuperClass`, the variable is treated as if it were referencing an instance of `SuperClass`. Therefore, it will have no knowledge of any of the methods declared specifically in `SubClass`. Note, though, that the overrides performed in `SubClass` will still be effective.

In the context you described, to access `someMethodExistOnlyInSubClass()` you would have to cast `s` to the type `SubClass`. Look below:

```
((SubClass) s).someMethodExistOnlyInSubClass();
```

Comment: or he should just re-write it to: SubClass s = new SubClass(parameters);

Comment: Indeed. However, there are situations in which it's useful to store a reference to an instance of a subclass in a variable of the type of it's superclass. For these situations, a cast is necessary to access the members of the subclass through that variable.

Comment: I understand  that, but i still dont get it why polymorphism can call for example: SubClass toString method when it is invoked from a SuperClass variable.

Comment: That happens because the object is the same no matter the type of the variable that references it. So even if you are referencing an instance of `SubClass` through a variable of the type `SuperClass`, the object remains the same. It's only a matter of whether or not the variable knows the type of object it's referencing.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do will work only when the method is defined in both Parent class and subclass.

```
    import java.util.*;
    class Parent 
    {
        public void sample()
        {
            System.out.println("Method of parent is getting Called");
        }
    }


    class Subclass extends Parent
    {
        public void sample()
        {
            System.out.println("Method of Child class is getting Called");
        }
    }

    public class Main
    {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Parent p = new Subclass();
            p.sample();
        }
    }

OUTPUT : Method of Child class is getting Called
```

If the method exists only in Child class. You will have to create an instance of Child class itself.

Something like this :

```
import java.util.*;
class Parent 
{

}

class Subclass extends Parent
{
    public void sample()
    {
        System.out.println("Method of Child class is getting Called");
    }
}

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Subclass p = new Subclass();
        p.sample();
    }
}
```

Or you can type cast it as mentioned in the earlier post

```
Parent p = new Subclass();
((Subclass)p).sample();
```

Answer (score 1):

An object is created based on its declaring class.
When you declare it as `SuperClass s` the object s wont have any method called `someMethodExistOnlyInSubClass` . So when you try to invoke this method, even before look at the subclass, you get a compile error.

The object `s` contrains only everything of the superclass, this object wont be aware of any subclass until u type cast the object to subclass.